# Retrieve all the comments from a large C project

Tags: c, comments

I have several directories full of C code, and I want to retrieve all of the /* */ comments from all of the code (.h files and .c files) in all of the directories and subdirectories, putting those comments all in a textfile (things don't need to be particularly orderly, just cram 'em all in there). How can I do this?

Any solution that's scriptable would be great...

Comment: You could do this easily if you have linux? just command line it :X

Comment: Why on earth would you want to do this? Hmm, I suppose looking for obscenities would be one reason, but you are better off searching the whole codebase for them.

Comment: Doesn't doxygen do exactly this? Or am I mistaken?

Comment: The default for Doxygen is not to display normal comments.  Doxygen looks for *special* comment blocks.

Comment: You'll have to realize that the statement: `const char junk[] = "/* not a comment */";` does not qualify as a comment.  Can a regex handle this case?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sed script, which prints all the /* */ comments but it will print "comments" in strings (as pointed out by Thomas Matthews) and it will not print // comments. Don't know what happens with nestet comments.

```
/\/\*/{
    bc
:a
    s/\///;Tz
:c
    s/^[^\/]*//;tb;Tb
:b
    s/^\/\*/\/\*/;Ta
:e
    s/\*\//\*\//;Td;s/\*\//\*\/\n/;x;tg
:g
    s/\(.\)/\1/;Tf;p;s/^.*$//
:f
    x;P;s/^.*\n//;bc
:d
    H;n;be
:z
}
```

To print all comments for all files in a directory, use it as follows:

```
for i in `find -iname "*.c" -or -iname "*.h"`; do echo ">>> $i"; sed -nf the.script.from.above < $i; done > output.txt
```

This won't handle filenames with whitespace in it and the output will not be pretty!

Cheers